# How to create multiline textbox in SharePoint Online using C#

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have some experience with C# and no experience with Sharepoint and have tried to find the answer to this simple question. What is the code for a multiline text box? I'm using Sharepoint in Office365.

Thanks!

Comment: Pls be specific. cant understand code for text box ?

Answer (score 2):

For Server Side, you can do like this:

```
list.Fields.Add("yourfieldname", SPFieldType.Note, false);
```

For SharePoint Online (which is your case), you should use CSOM, like the following:

```
 ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(webUrl);
 Web rootWeb = clientContext.Site.RootWeb;
 string notesField = "<Field  Type='Note' Name='" + InternalName+ "' StaticName='" + Displayname + "' DisplayName='" + Displayname + "' Group='" + groupName + "'  NumLines='6' RichText='True' Sortable='FALSE' />";
 rootWeb.Fields.AddFieldAsXml(notesField , true, AddFieldOptions.AddFieldInternalNameHint);
 clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```